# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application. Crash on launch

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

When I try to run the react native app on android in debug mode, it crashes as soon as it launches without any error. Opening the app a few times throws an exception with the error mentioned below  Everything was working fine yesterday, but today it won't work anymore. Any help would be very appreciated.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.sensights.MainApplication package com.sensights: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.sensights.MainApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~XrS92eK0FL1rdOtvadinMg==/com.sensights-7FJVzYCKNOkXrB-fDIbxyQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~XrS92eK0FL1rdOtvadinMg==/com.sensights-7FJVzYCKNOkXrB-fDIbxyQ==/lib/arm64, /data/app/~~XrS92eK0FL1rdOtvadinMg==/com.sensights-7FJVzYCKNOkXrB-fDIbxyQ==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/system_ext/lib64]]
    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:1385)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:7054)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:275)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2168)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:210)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:299)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8280)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:576)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1073)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.sensights.MainApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~XrS92eK0FL1rdOtvadinMg==/com.sensights-7FJVzYCKNOkXrB-fDIbxyQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~XrS92eK0FL1rdOtvadinMg==/com.sensights-7FJVzYCKNOkXrB-fDIbxyQ==/lib/arm64, /data/app/~~XrS92eK0FL1rdOtvadinMg==/com.sensights-7FJVzYCKNOkXrB-fDIbxyQ==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/system_ext/lib64]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:259)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateApplication(AppComponentFactory.java:76)
    at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateApplication(CoreComponentFactory.java:52)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1177)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:1377)
    ... 10 more
```

I tried cleaning the project and building again but it didn't work.
This is my `android/app/build.gradle` :

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

import com.android.build.OutputFile

/**
 * The react.gradle file registers a task for each build variant (e.g. bundleDebugJsAndAssets
 * and bundleReleaseJsAndAssets).
 * These basically call `react-native bundle` with the correct arguments during the Android build
 * cycle. By default, bundleDebugJsAndAssets is skipped, as in debug/dev mode we prefer to load the
 * bundle directly from the development server. Below you can see all the possible configurations
 * and their defaults. If you decide to add a configuration block, make sure to add it before the
 * `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` line.
 *
 * project.ext.react = [
 *   // the name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
 *   bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
 *
 *   // the entry file for bundle generation. If none specified and
 *   // "index.android.js" exists, it will be used. Otherwise "index.js" is
 *   // default. Can be overridden with ENTRY_FILE environment variable.
 *   entryFile: "index.android.js",
 *
 *   // https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance#enable-the-ram-format
 *   bundleCommand: "ram-bundle",
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in debug mode
 *   bundleInDebug: false,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in release mode
 *   bundleInRelease: true,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in another build variant (if configured).
 *   // See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'bundleIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'bundleIn${buildType}'
 *   // bundleInFreeDebug: true,
 *   // bundleInPaidRelease: true,
 *   // bundleInBeta: true,
 *
 *   // whether to disable dev mode in custom build variants (by default only disabled in release)
 *   // for example: to disable dev mode in the staging build type (if configured)
 *   devDisabledInStaging: true,
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${buildType}'
 *
 *   // the root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives
 *   root: "../../",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in debug mode
 *   jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in release mode
 *   jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in debug mode
 *   resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in release mode
 *   resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
 *
 *   // by default the gradle tasks are skipped if none of the JS files or assets change; this means
 *   // that we don't look at files in android/ or ios/ to determine whether the tasks are up to
 *   // date; if you have any other folders that you want to ignore for performance reasons (gradle
 *   // indexes the entire tree), add them here. Alternatively, if you have JS files in android/
 *   // for example, you might want to remove it from here.
 *   inputExcludes: ["android/**", "ios/**"],
 *
 *   // override which node gets called and with what additional arguments
 *   nodeExecutableAndArgs: ["node"],
 *
 *   // supply additional arguments to the packager
 *   extraPackagerArgs: []
 * ]
 */

project.ext.react = [
    enableHermes: false,  // clean and rebuild if changing
    bundleInDebug: false,
    bundleInRelease: true,
    entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"

Project background_geolocation = project(':react-native-background-geolocation')
apply from: "${background_geolocation.projectDir}/app.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

/**
 * The preferred build flavor of JavaScriptCore.
 *
 * For example, to use the international variant, you can use:
 * `def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+'`
 *
 * The international variant includes ICU i18n library and necessary data
 * allowing to use e.g. `Date.toLocaleString` and `String.localeCompare` that
 * give correct results when using with locales other than en-US.  Note that
 * this variant is about 6MiB larger per architecture than default.
 */
def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'

/**
 * Whether to enable the Hermes VM.
 *
 * This should be set on project.ext.react and mirrored here.  If it is not set
 * on project.ext.react, JavaScript will not be compiled to Hermes Bytecode
 * and the benefits of using Hermes will therefore be sharply reduced.
 */
def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get("enableHermes", false)

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding true
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sensights"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 35
        versionName "1.5.1"
        multiDexEnabled true 
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable true
            // enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'sensights'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
//release will be here
 release {
            storeFile file('keystore.jks')
            storePassword 'sensights'
            keyAlias 'upload'
            keyPassword 'sensights'
        }
    // release {
    //         if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE')) {
    //             storeFile file(MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE)
    //             storePassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_PASSWORD
    //             keyAlias MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_ALIAS
    //             keyPassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_PASSWORD
    //         }
        }

    
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.
            //needs to be signingConfigs.release
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst "lib/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so"
        pickFirst "lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so"
        pickFirst "lib/x86/libc++_shared.so"
        pickFirst "lib/x86_64/libc++_shared.so"
    }

    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }

        }
    }

    project.afterEvaluate {
        def isAndroidLibrary = plugins.hasPlugin("com.android.library")
        def variants = isAndroidLibrary ? android.libraryVariants : android.applicationVariants
           variants.all { def variant ->
        def targetName = variant.name.capitalize()
        def mergeResourcesTask = tasks.findByName("merge${targetName}Resources")
        def assetsCopyTask = tasks.findByName("copy${targetName}BundledJs")
        mergeResourcesTask.dependsOn(assetsCopyTask)
        logger.warn("Making task ${mergeResourcesTask} depend on ${assetsCopyTask}")
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules

    implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1"

//     implementation "org.jetbrains:kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"

    implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0"

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
      exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
    }
    implementation group: 'com.zendesk', name: 'chat', version: '3.1.0'
    implementation group: 'com.zendesk', name: 'messaging', version: '5.1.0'
    // implementation project(':react-native-contacts')

    // implementation project(':react-native-geocoder')

    // implementation project(':react-native-immediate-phone-call')

    // implementation project(':react-native-location')

    // Pushy SDK for Android
    implementation 'me.pushy:sdk:1.0.67'

    // Pushy SDK for React Native Android
    implementation 'me.pushy:sdk-react-native:1.0.15'

    implementation project(':WebRTCModule')


    if (enableHermes) {
        def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/"
        debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
        releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }

    //lifecycle
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'


    //Coroutines
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.7'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.7'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.2.0'

    //CameraX
//     implementation "androidx.camera:camera-core:1.0.2"
//     implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:1.0.2"
//     implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:1.0.2"
//     implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:1.0.0-alpha28"

    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-core:1.0.2"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:1.0.2"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:1.0.2"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:1.0.0-alpha28"

    //ML
    implementation 'com.google.mlkit:face-detection:16.1.2'
    implementation "org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:2.2.0"
    implementation "org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-gpu:2.2.0"
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-support:0.0.0-nightly'

    //OpenCV
    //implementation "com.quickbirdstudios:opencv:3.4.5"

    //Retrofit
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.7.2"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0"

    //Constrain, Material , Androidx
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0"
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2"
    implementation "com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3"
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'  

}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
```

Here is my `android/build.gradle` file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        googlePlayServicesLocationVersion = "17.0.0"  // Or higher.
        // buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        buildToolsVersion = "30.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 24
        compileSdkVersion = 31
        targetSdkVersion = 30
        appCompatVersion = "1.1.0"      // Or higher.  Required for new AndroidX compatibility.
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
        playServicesVersion = "17.0.0"
//        androidMapsUtilsVersion = "+0.5"
        // # Only using Android Support libraries
        androidXCore = "1.3.1"
        androidXAnnotation = "1.3.0"
        androidXBrowser = "1.3.0"
        kotlin_version = "1.6.21"

        // buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        // minSdkVersion = 16
        // compileSdkVersion = 28
        // targetSdkVersion = 28
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
    dependencies {
    classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3")
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }
        maven {
            // Required for react-native-background-geolocation
            url("${project(':react-native-background-geolocation').projectDir}/libs")
        }
        maven {
            // Required for react-native-background-fetch
            url("${project(':react-native-background-fetch').projectDir}/libs")
        }
        maven { url 'https://zendesk.jfrog.io/zendesk/repo' }
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }

    }
}
subprojects {
    afterEvaluate {project ->
        if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
            android {
                compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
                buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.sensights">

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <!-- Pushy Permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <!-- End Pushy Permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
    <uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_GRANT_RUNTIME_PERMISSIONS "/>

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false" android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <!-- react-native-background-geolocation licence -->
        <meta-data android:name="com.transistorsoft.locationmanager.license" android:value="6e0b13cf6c80c6a541fb5b8797215cf82080fb58e658d32c72ec2f1a523ee9a0" />

      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

                  <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <!-- <data android:scheme="http" /> -->
        <data android:scheme="https" android:host="login.sensights.ai" />
         <!-- <data android:scheme="app" android:host="open.my.app" /> -->
    </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />

      <!-- GOOGLE API -->
      <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="AIzaSyCM3R8cZQht5FIFqWEoEGiJNiquht_CVUU"/>

      <!-- <activity android:name=".bluetooth.DeviceScanActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" />
      <activity android:name=".bluetooth.DeviceControlActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" />
      <service android:name=".bluetooth.BluetoothLeService" android:enabled="true"/> -->

        <!-- Pushy Declarations -->
        <!-- Pushy Notification Receiver -->
        <!-- Do not modify - internal BroadcastReceiver that forwards notifications to the internal notification service-->
        <receiver android:name="me.pushy.sdk.react.receivers.PushReceiver" android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <!-- Do not modify this -->
                <action android:name="pushy.me" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <!-- Pushy Update Receiver -->
        <!-- Do not modify - internal BroadcastReceiver that restarts the listener service -->
        <receiver android:name="me.pushy.sdk.receivers.PushyUpdateReceiver" android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <!-- Pushy Boot Receiver -->
        <!-- Do not modify - internal BroadcastReceiver that restarts the listener service -->
        <receiver android:name="me.pushy.sdk.receivers.PushyBootReceiver" android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <!-- Pushy Socket Service -->
        <!-- Do not modify - internal service -->
        <service android:name="me.pushy.sdk.services.PushySocketService" android:stopWithTask="false" />

        <!-- Pushy Job Service (added in Pushy SDK 1.0.35) -->
        <!-- Do not modify - internal service -->
        <service android:name="me.pushy.sdk.services.PushyJobService"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"
            android:stopWithTask="false" />

        <!-- End Pushy Declarations -->

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: once you create class MainApplication and it may be you change its destination check pakage name it is on same place where as pakage name show  on top of class